# UILabel "vibrates" all the time

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I recently noticed that my UILabels in my project became "vibrating", which means their widths (or maybe locations) change all the time and never stop. 
All these "vibrating" labels are using dynamic font, set as ShrinkContent.

I would like to ask how to solve this problem, or just I shouldn't use UILabel in such a way?
Thank you.

Comment: show your code, how do you assign frame to the label.

Comment: I don`t have any code - my settings are declared in editor :)
From Code i`m just changing UiLabel text

Comment: How have you anchored your Label?

Comment: Yes, but when i removing anchors - problem still exists